# Appropriate public exponent choice for RSA encryption

Tags: rsa

From what I understand, we can arbitrarily choose an exponent e as long as 
 $\gcd(e,\phi(n)) =1$.

- But what is the most appropriate choice for it?
- Should it be small compared to $\phi(n)$ or approach it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> we can arbitrarily choose an exponent $e$ as long as $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$.

**No.** If we want any security, we further :

- Must NOT choose $e=1$, because that makes $x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$ the identity function over $[0,n)$.
- Must NOT choose $e$ in a way revealing information about of $\phi(n)$ or the factors of $n$ beyond that $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$. For example, we can not choose  $e$ as $e=p$, nor $e=\phi(n)-3$, nor as the first integer larger than $\phi(n)/42$ with $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$, nor in such a way that $d$ is small.
- Should choose $e$ not too small *if* there is a regulatory minimum *or* we have little assurance about how the key will be used. This mitigates to some degree some poor message padding and some poor decryption implementations. Using $e\ge2\log_2(n)$ should be technically OK for all except the worst (or absent) paddings.

> What is the most appropriate choice for $e$?

The simple, safe, standard option is: choose $e=F_4=2^{(2^4)}+1=65537$, *then* choose prime factors $p$ of $n$ with $p\bmod e\ne1$. This test (and factors being distinct of $e$, which holds for suitably large factors) is enough to ensure $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$, since we picked $e$ prime. And picking factors as a function of $e$, rather than the other way around, ensures minimal information is revealed about $\phi(n)$ and factors of $n$. $65537$ is large enough that $e\ge2\log_2(n)$ is met for practical sizes of $n$, and conforms to recommendations by all major security authorities.

If for some reason we must choose $e$ after factors of $n$, a common practice is to choose the lowest $e$ above some minimum with $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$. A very slightly safer practice would be to choose $e$ randomly in some interval $[m,2m)$ until $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$, but that's overkill (and there's seldom a good reason to choose $e$ after the factors of $n$ anyway).

> Should $e$ be small compared to $\phi(n)$ or approach it?

The former: $e$ should be small, and $\phi(n)$ large. There is often a conventional upper limit to $e$, like $e<2^{256}$ in [FIPS 186-5](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A128%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C447%2C0%5D), $e<n$ in [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr), or $e<2^{32}$ in some Windows APIs, when $\phi(n)$ must be in the thousands of bits (and of bit size equal to that of $n$, or one less for $n$ slightly above a power of two). And for reasons already discussed, $e$ must not be chosen close to $\phi(n)$ or any related quantity, including [$\lambda(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)). Also, it is typically best to keep $e$ not too large for performance reason: public-key use requires time roughly proportional to the bit size of $e$. The standard $e=F_4=2^{(2^4)}+1$ is attractive because [encryption with it is faster](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/13861) than with larger values of $e$ (and as well as most lower values). Still, that $e$ makes public-key use about 8 times slower than with $e=3$; the latter can be a good choice when the performance of public-key use is paramount, appropriate padding and implementations are used, and regulatory requirements allow.

Answer (score 2):

> But what is the most appropriate choice for it?

For public exponent $e$, small values are preferred like $\{3, 5, 17, 257, \text{ or } 65537\}$. With this, we can guarantee that the number of operations is low. We can control this with our choice. Of course, for the choice of $e$, we must have $\gcd(e,p)=1$ for any prime $p$ divides the modulus $n$. This guarantees that we have the inverse of $e$ such that $e\cdot d = 1 \bmod \phi(n)$, and $\gcd(e',n) = \gcd(e,n)$

> Should it be small compared to $\phi(n)$ or approach it?

You can choose a public exponent $e'$ bigger than $\phi(n)$, however due to the congruence, we can always find an $e$ such that $ e' \equiv e \bmod \phi(n)$ with $e < \phi(n)$.

Of course, RSA should never be used without **proper padding scheme**. For example, if you use $e=3$ without a proper padding scheme than you will be vulnerable to [cube-root attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_attack).

- For encryption, you can use [PKCS#1 v1.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) padding or [Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) (OAEP), Prefer OAEP, PKCS#1 v1.5 has many attacks and hard to implement correctly.
- For signatures, you can use [Probabilistic Signature Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme) (PSS).

And note that **[RSA Signing is Not RSA Decryption](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php)!**