# Is gcd(e,p−1)=1=gcd(e,q−1) similar to gcd(e,phi(n))=1?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, prime-numbers

I wonder, is $\gcd(e,p−1)=1=\gcd(e,q−1)$ similar to $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$ ??

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se What is the origin of this question? do you know that $\varphi(p\cdot q) = (p-1)(q-1)$ and from there what can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you for your clues and the origin question is from this [link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108624/in-rsa-encryption-can-i-choose-the-public-exponent-e-m-modulus-or-e-%cf%86n?noredirect=1#comment232708_108624) @fgrieu

Answer (score 1):

If $n=p\,q$, and $p$ and $q$ are prime, and $p\ne q$, then $\varphi(p\cdot q) = (p-1)(q-1)$, from which it follows that for any integer $e$, the propositions $\gcd(e,p-1)=1=\gcd(e,q-1)$ and $\gcd(e,\varphi(n))=1$ are equivalent.

Each of the conditions $n=p\,q$, $p$ and $q$ prime, and $p\ne q$, is necessary for the equivalence to hold for all $e$. These conditions are standard in RSA. For an example proving that $p\ne q$ is necessary, consider $p=q=e=3$: it holds $\gcd(e,p-1)=1=\gcd(e,q-1)$, but $\gcd(e,\varphi(9))=\gcd(e,6)=3$.

When generating an RSA key pair with a desired $e$ (which is common), $\gcd(e,p-1)=1=\gcd(e,q-1)$ is convenient, because it allows generating suitable $p$ and $q$ essentially independently. Also, when $e$ is prime (which is common: $e$ is typically a [Fermat prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) $F_i=2^{(2^i)}+1$ for some $i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}\,$), this condition becomes $p\bmod e\ne1$ and $q\bmod e\ne1$, which are easy to check or ascertain by construction of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thank you so much , Your answer is very useful for me

Comment: I'm still expecting proof for the first part.

Comment: @kelalaka: the proof uses that for all integers $e,u,v\in\mathbb N^*$, it holds $\gcd(e,u\,v)=1$ $\iff$ $(\gcd(e,u)=1$ and $\gcd(e,v)=1)$ [which itself follows from the fact that prime divisors of $u\,v$ are the union of prime divisors of $u$ and prime divisors of $v$]. That's instantiated with $u=p-1$, $v=q-1$, $u\,v=\varphi(p\,q)=\varphi(n)$.